# Importing data from Postgres using OLE DB source not showing all data

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, t-sql, ssis

I am using OLE DB source to import data from a Postgres database to SQL Server database using OLE DB Destination. When I execute the package, it is running successfully.
Eventhough it is saying 'N' number of records are written to OLE DB destination, I couldn't find all  records always in PostgreSQL DB destination table. There are no error records.

Like for example I query my Employee table in  Postgres :

```
EmpId Name PositionId
10    Bob  1
25    Alex 2
54    Mary 22
```

When I try to visualize data in the OLE DB Source with a connection manager pointing to Postgres, I only find :

```
EmpId Name PositionId
10    Bob  1
54    Mary 22
```

I can't find the record :

```
EmpId Name PositionId
25    Alex 2
```

Comment: Are you using SSIS? if you do, right-click the arrow that connects OLEDB Source to OLEDB Destination, enable the Data View. When you're running the package, there will be a preview of the data before inserting to the destination, do you find your data there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using ODBC Postgresql Connection :

- I configure a PostgreSQL connection in the ODBC Administration Tool.
- I chose the correct version acc(32/64 bit) and opened the ODBC
  Administration Toollike below :

[image]

- I chose the Add button:

[image]

- I selected the PostgreSQL Unicode driver and Clicked Finish. It will open
  up the following window. I fill the fields according to the database
  related properties that I have.

[image]